# Pagespeed указывает на блокирование CSS

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Есть проблема: оптимизировал уже весь код *CSS*. Однако *pagespeed* ругается на него. Переносил его уже и в `<head>`, и в `<footer>`, и за пределы `<html>` - не помогает. Кто сталкивался с таким? Как побороть?

Pagespeed результаты [**здесь**](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstage.acservis.com.ua%2Findex&tab=desktop)

Comment: То, что показывает у вас google pagespeed по ссылке, вы можете смело игнорировать.

Comment: Да, но владелец сайта хочет 100/100. В это вся сложность

Comment: скорее всего проблема в том, что "Попробуйте отложить ее или асинхронно загрузить блокирующие ресурсы", google pagespeed, не может прочитать эти два файла.

Comment: стили css объедините в один файл

Comment: Результаты в самый раз: _Сервис PageSpeed Insights получил от сервера ответ 404.
100 / 100Рекомендации

Поздравляем! Проблемы не обнаружены._

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, исправте все ошибки в версте, такие как

> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico"   </head>

Также попробуйте использовать CDN для бутстрапа.

Если это не поможет, единственный выход встроить весь css в тэг `<style>`, сам Google так и делает.

Comment: Исправил. Однако все равно ругается. Уже и в один файл css пробовал сводить - не даёт результата.

Comment: @Platon Вы пробывали поместить весь `CSS` внутрь `HTML` в тэг `style`. Так он не будет кэшироватся, но вроде бы `Google` так дает максимальную оценку.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, Google из-за ошибок в разметке относит скрипт к области `<head>`.

Посмотрите в [валидатор html](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fstage.acservis.com.ua%2Findex&showsource=yes&showoutline=yes). Он после 185 предупреждения/ошибки ругается:

> Fatal Error: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.

и это место как раз приходится на

> `↩</html>↩<script defer src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></scri`